# Pandas Timedelta in Days

Tags: python, numpy, timestamp, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas called 'munged_data' with two columns 'entry_date' and 'dob' which i have converted to Timestamps using pd.to_timestamp.I am trying to figure out how to calculate ages of people based on the time difference between 'entry_date' and 'dob' and to do this i need to get the difference in days between the two columns ( so that i can then do somehting like round(days/365.25). I do not seem to be able to find a way to do this using a vectorized operation. When I do munged_data.entry_date-munged_data.dob i get the following :

```
internal_quote_id
2                    15685977 days, 23:54:30.457856
3                    11651985 days, 23:49:15.359744
4                     9491988 days, 23:39:55.621376
7                     11907004 days, 0:10:30.196224
9                    15282164 days, 23:30:30.196224
15                  15282227 days, 23:50:40.261632
```

However i do not seem to be able to extract the days as an integer so that i can continue with my calculation. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: TLDR: `(df['entry_date'] - df['dob']).dt.days` (see my answer below)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need 0.11 for this (0.11rc1 is out, final prob next week)

```
In [9]: df = DataFrame([ Timestamp('20010101'), Timestamp('20040601') ])

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
                    0
0 2001-01-01 00:00:00
1 2004-06-01 00:00:00

In [11]: df = DataFrame([ Timestamp('20010101'), 
                          Timestamp('20040601') ],columns=['age'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
                  age
0 2001-01-01 00:00:00
1 2004-06-01 00:00:00

In [13]: df['today'] = Timestamp('20130419')

In [14]: df['diff'] = df['today']-df['age']

In [16]: df['years'] = df['diff'].apply(lambda x: float(x.item().days)/365)

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
                  age               today                diff      years
0 2001-01-01 00:00:00 2013-04-19 00:00:00 4491 days, 00:00:00  12.304110
1 2004-06-01 00:00:00 2013-04-19 00:00:00 3244 days, 00:00:00   8.887671
```

You need this odd apply at the end because not yet full support for timedelta64[ns] scalars (e.g. like how we use Timestamps now for datetime64[ns], coming in 0.12)

Comment: Thanks Jeff very helpful i did not know abou the item() method. I managed to do it with 0.10

Comment: great! Here's some recipes and a link to new docs (in 0.11), http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#miscellaneous

Comment: You don't need this approach which requires a specific pandas version. Instead, follow the suggestion from @dant `(df['entry_date'] - df['dob']).dt.days`

Answer (score 127):

Using the Pandas type [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timedeltas.html) available since v0.15.0 you also can do:

```
In[1]: import pandas as pd
In[2]: df = pd.DataFrame([ pd.Timestamp('20150111'), 
                           pd.Timestamp('20150301') ], columns=['date'])
In[3]: df['today'] = pd.Timestamp('20150315')
In[4]: df
Out[4]: 
        date      today
0 2015-01-11 2015-03-15
1 2015-03-01 2015-03-15

In[5]: (df['today'] - df['date']).dt.days
Out[5]: 
0    63
1    14
dtype: int64
```

Comment: brilliant! I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `Timedelta.dt.days` is 100 times faster than `apply(lambda x: x.days())`

Comment: seriously, why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if you still need it, but in Pandas 0.14 i  usually use .astype('timedelta64[X]') method
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html (frequency conversion)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ pd.Timestamp('20010101'), pd.Timestamp('20040605') ])
df.ix[0]-df.ix[1]
```

Returns:

> ```
> 0   -1251 days
> dtype: timedelta64[ns]
> ```

```
(df.ix[0]-df.ix[1]).astype('timedelta64[Y]')
```

Returns:

```
  0   -4
 dtype: float64
```

Hope that will help

Comment: I just googled and found this question. My problem is that I was using something similar as Jeff answer for my dataframe. However, I have like a million lines, so apply is kind of slow. Using `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` is a way faster method (about 200x)

Answer (score 8):

Let's specify that you have a pandas series named time_difference which has type
`numpy.timedelta64[ns]`

One way of extracting just the day (or whatever desired attribute) is the following:

```
just_day = time_difference.apply(lambda x: pd.tslib.Timedelta(x).days)
```

This function is used because the numpy.timedelta64 object does not have a 'days' attribute.

Answer (score 7):

To convert any type of data into days just use `pd.Timedelta().days`:

```
pd.Timedelta(1985, unit='Y').days
84494
```