# change timedelta to integers for all columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with columns of various attributes ( time delta, numeric, date etc.) Is there a way to replace the columns of the data frame, which have time delta data, to numeric data?

My data looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5,10]\
               ,'business':['FRC','FRC','FRC']\
               ,'b':[2,3,4]\
               ,'c':[1,2,3]})


df['a']=pd.to_timedelta(df['a'],unit='d')
df['b']=pd.to_timedelta(df['b'],unit='d')
df.dtypes
```

I want to change all columns to numeric .
**Note: my column names keep changing.**

Ed

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: added sample data

Comment: do you need `df['a']=pd.to_timedelta(df['a'],unit='d').dt.days
df['b']=pd.to_timedelta(df['b'],unit='d').dt.days` ?

Comment: Yes. I need the two lines above. I added the lines above to show how my data currently looks.

Comment: so it is what you need? [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28900208) ?

Comment: no. What i need is something that performs the following logic:1. get all the columns in the dataframe of timedelta. 2. replace them with numeric data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
c = df.select_dtypes('timedelta').columns

df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: x.dt.days)
print (df)
    a business  b  c
0   1      FRC  2  1
1   5      FRC  3  2
2  10      FRC  4  3
```