# How to return CUMSUM of Days in Dates - Python

Tags: python, pandas

How do I return the CumSum number of days for the dates provided?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-01-01','2019-01-03','2019-01-05',
             '2019-01-06','2019-01-07','2019-01-08',
             '2019-01-09','2019-01-12','2019-01-013']})
```

`df['date'].cumsum()` does not work here.

Desired dataframe:

```
          date  Cumsum days
0   2019-01-01            0
1   2019-01-03            2
2   2019-01-05            4
3   2019-01-06            5
4   2019-01-07            6
5   2019-01-08            7
6   2019-01-09            8
7   2019-01-12            9
8  2019-01-013           11
```

Comment: You don't really want the "cumsum"; you just want the timedelta between each date and the very first date. Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103238/pandas-timedelta-in-days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is calling `diff`, `fillna` and `cumsum`

```
df['cumsum days'] = df['date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).cumsum()

Out[2044]:
        date  cumsum days
0 2019-01-01          0.0
1 2019-01-03          2.0
2 2019-01-05          4.0
3 2019-01-06          5.0
4 2019-01-07          6.0
5 2019-01-08          7.0
6 2019-01-09          8.0
7 2019-01-12         11.0
8 2019-01-13         12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this should work:

```
def generate_time_delta_column(df, time_column, date_first_online_column):
    return (df[time_column] - df[date_first_online_column]).dt.days
```